# Azure PowerShell-Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, account, runbook

Working on this as below - Using a power-shell script inside the Automation Account for run-book. The power-shell script will help in adding a rule inside the resource of the function-app of the networking rule. But somehow the following happens -

1. Not able to login the azure account
2. And it says Subscription ID doesn't exists. (Login is done via Service principle)

Code for reference

```
$azureAplicationId="XXXX" 
$azureTenantId="XXXXX" 
$azurePassword=ConvertToSecureString "XXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force 
$psCred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId ,$azurePassword) 
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXXX" 
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "XXXXX" -WebAppName "XXXXX" -Name "iprule" -Priority 100 -Action Allow -IpAddress x.x.x.x/x –
```

Comment: Message after running the runbook - The subscription id XXXX doesn't exis

Comment: For readability, you can use ``` code ``` block and specify a bit more info on user account.

Comment: Thanks! What Am making to understand is  - When i run the above powershell code, It has the message like subscription doesnt exists.

Comment: You wanted me explain anything Please let me know.

Comment: Can someone Please help me in the above errors am getting:
1.When I m executing line 1-5 Login via service principle am getting logged in correctly
2. When I add Line to add IP rule to function app and execute it -it says client sub cant be null.
3. When I try to eradicate the above error and use line 6 as select-Azure Subscription,it says sub id doesnt exists.

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan Have you configured Azure RABC role for the service principal in the subscription : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview.

Comment: No I didn't do that.

Comment: But I have added roles assignment for service principle and added Contributor role to the service principle i had created.

Comment: Now the error client subscription ID cannot be null isn't coming and hence my problem has been resolved.

Comment: @AnirudhBragadeesan, please add an answer to this question.

Comment: Sure-Answer is already shared above.No Problem I will share it here once again.

Comment: I added the Contributor Role to the Service Principal.